# Type/value mismatch in member function of C++ template class

Tags: c++, templates, g++

I have a code similar to this one:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T> class Functor
{
    T *pthis;
    void (T::*fun)(void);
public:
    Functor(T* punteroThis, void (T::*funcion)() ) : pthis(punteroThis), fun(funcion) { }
    void operator() (void);
};

template<typename T>
void Functor<T>::operator() ()
{
    (pthis->*fun)();
}

template<typename T> class myTimer
{
    /*
       omitted 'typename' so that T inside task
       is the same as T in class myTimer
    */
    template<T> class task
    {
        unsigned id;
        bool active;
        Functor<T> fun;
        unsigned interval;
    public:
        task(unsigned id_, bool active_, Functor<T> fun_, unsigned interval_) : id(id_), active(active_), fun(fun_), interval(interval_) { }
    };


    void print(myTimer::task<T> const& t);    // << this is not working

};

template<typename T>
void myTimer<T>::print(myTimer::task<T> const& t)
{
    std::cout << "id = " << t.id << '\n';
    std::cout << "active = " << t.active << '\n';
    std::cout << "interval = " << t.interval << std::endl;
}
```

When calling the compiler

```
g++ -Wall -g -std=c++11 myTimer.h -c
```

I've got the following errors, in both declaration and definition of `print()`:

```
error:   type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for
      ‘template<class T> template<T <anonymous> > class myTimer<T>::task’
error:   expected a constant of type ‘T’, got ‘T’
```

I also tried with `typename` and had the same output. I don't figure out how to solve it. Any idea of what's happening?

I am using g++ version 4.8.4 on a Linux platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is incorrect:

```
/*
   omitted 'typename' so that T inside task
   is the same as T in class myTimer
*/
template<T> class task
```

If you want T inside task to be the same as T in the containing scope, just leave out the `template<T>` entirely.

Then you had:

```
void print(myTimer::task<T> const& t);    // << this is not working
```

Where you just wanted:

```
void print(myTimer::task const& t);
```

Comment: And use `struct` instead of `class` or make the definition of `task` public.

Comment: Thank you! Happy new year :)